# Operand type mismatch for "jmp"

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly

I everyone.

I have a problem with the following piece of code:

```
asm volatile("         \
  cli;                 \
  mov %0, %%ecx;       \
  mov %1, %%esp;       \
  mov %2, %%ebp;       \
  mov %3, %%cr3;       \
  mov $0x12345, %%eax; \
  sti;                 \
  jmp *%%ecx           "
             : : "r"(eip), "r"(esp), "r"(ebp), "r"(current_directory -> physical_address));
```

The problem is on the "jmp" instruction, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
cc -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -c -o task.o task.c
ERROR : operand type mismatch for `jmp'
```

Comment: Are you compiling as 64-bit?  Because 32-bit operand-size for `jmp` is only available in 32-bit mode.  (or 16-bit mode).  Use `-m32`.

Comment: Yes, i had in mind to build for 32bit, and i missed it. Thank you, really helpful!

Comment: Close as a simple typo?

Comment: Also, changing `esp` and `ebp` inside a compiled function is not guaranteed to behave properly. Perhaps you want to write the entire function in assembly.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you for the advice. Currently it's giving me some problems, and they may be related to this